# Stream video with MPMoviePlayer while streaming separate audio file in background, all from remote URL

Tags: objective-c, iphone, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudioplayer

So we want to be able to stream a video from a website.

We also want to be able to do the same with a separate audio file.

The reason why we need them to stream separately and can't integrate the two into just a video is because we need the user to be able to scrub the video however the audio should keep playing. Is there a way to get MPMoviePlayerController to stream the video on button click, as well as stream audio "underneath" the video, playing at the same time, using maybe something such as AVAudioPlayer (unless there's other classes that make this easier).

Anyone know how to do something like this?

Comment: As i know, iPhone only allows one audio stream playing, if you launch a movie player, it will terminate the audio session of the other controllers. I guess why they design iPhone in this way is they want to confirm that an incoming phone call can mute all other audio streams. Users may not like there are other voices in the background while making a call.

Comment: All the videos we will be using contain no audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, AVAudioPlayer can't play streaming audio.

You should try Matt Gallapher's code sample --> https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer.  This class is capable of playing a mp3 over network while another video/audio stream is being playing via MPMoviePlayer.